# Android Studio won't start on OpenSUSE (too many files open)

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio, opensuse

I haven't posted on StackOverflow in quite a while, so forgive me if I'm placing this in the wrong area, but here's the issue:

I recently downloaded Android Studio for my relatively freshly installed OpenSUSE system, have installed openjdk-devel, and whenever I try to start studio.sh the splash screen comes up, makes it about 70% of the way through loading, and then spams the console with:

```html
[   7146]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - /home/user/.AndroidStudio1.3/system/caches/names.dat.len (Too many open files) 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/.AndroidStudio1.3/system/caches/names.dat.len (Too many open files)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
 at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile$1.execute(ResizeableMappedFile.java:119)
 at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile$1.execute(ResizeableMappedFile.java:114)
 at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doIOOperation(FileUtilRt.java:700)
 at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.writeLength(ResizeableMappedFile.java:114)
 at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.readLength(ResizeableMappedFile.java:164)
 at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.<init>(ResizeableMappedFile.java:55)
 at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:82)
 at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:38)
 at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:53)
 at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:46)
 at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:32)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:244)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:319)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:319)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:319)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:319)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:319)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:319)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:319)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:319)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:319)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.connect(FSRecords.java:160)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.connect(FSRecords.java:518)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.initComponent(PersistentFSImpl.java:89)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:568)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:550)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:268)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:127)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:116)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
 at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:550)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.java:168)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ApplicationImpl.java:533)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:199)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:194)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFileManager.getInstance(VirtualFileManager.java:44)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem$LocalFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(LocalFileSystem.java:40)
 at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem.getInstance(LocalFileSystem.java:44)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl$1.beforeFileBasedStorageCreate(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:85)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.createFileStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:212)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.createStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:185)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.getStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:102)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.initPersistentComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.java:315)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.java:75)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.initializeComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:177)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:566)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
 at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:125)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:354)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:116)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:87)
 at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:101)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:499)
 at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:481)
 at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
 at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
 at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
[   7150]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - Android Studio 1.3.1  Build #AI-141.2135290 
[   7151]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - JDK: 1.7.0_85 
[   7151]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - VM: OpenJDK Server VM 
[   7151]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
[   7151]  ERROR - j.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile - OS: Linux
```

And I'm sort of at my wit's end here.  I've tried linking to both openjdk as well as Oracle's latest JDK version.  I've tried playing with the number of maximum open files (set in /etc/environment/limits.conf), but that doesn't seem to do anything despite the error indicating an abundance of open files.  I've tried upgrading to openjdk1.8, downgrading to 1.7, reinstalling everything multiple times, but I just can't seem to launch the thing.

Is this a legitimate bug or critical user error?  Any ideas about where I could look to maybe solve this?

Edit:
/etc/environment/limits.conf

```html
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
#
#Where:
#<domain> can be:
#        - a user name
#        - a group name, with @group syntax
#        - the wildcard *, for default entry
#        - the wildcard %, can be also used with %group syntax,
#                 for maxlogin limit
#
#<type> can have the two values:
#        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits
#        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
#
#<item> can be one of the following:
#        - core - limits the core file size (KB)
#        - data - max data size (KB)
#        - fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open files
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
#        - cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
#        - nproc - max number of processes
#        - as - address space limit (KB)
#        - maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
#        - maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
#        - priority - the priority to run user process with
#        - locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
#        - sigpending - max number of pending signals
#        - msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
#        - nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to values: [-20, 19]
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
#
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
#

#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4

* hard nofile 65535
* soft nofile 65535
root soft nofile 65535
root hard nofile 65535

# End of file
```

uname -a

```html
Linux susebart 3.16.7-21-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 14 07:11:37 UTC 2015 (93c1539) i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

cat /proc/version

```html
Linux version 3.16.7-21-desktop (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140627 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 212064] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 14 07:11:37 UTC 2015 (93c1539)
```

Here's some mysterious output from the shell:

```
$ whoami
corey
$ ulimit -Hn
256
$ ulimit -Sn
256
$ su 
$ whoami
root
$ ulimit -Hn
65535
$ ulimit -Sn
65535
$ su corey
$ whoami
corey
$ ulimit -Hn
65535
$ ulimit -Sn
65535
$ exit
$ exit // getting back to login shell
$ whoami
corey
$ ulimit -Hn
256
$ ulimit -Sn
256
```

So it looks like the limits are changed properly when a new shell is opened (even without switching to root first in the case of the nested su above), but not when the machine is started or new shells are opened.  I confirmed that by running su USERNAME ./studio.sh I'm able to start the program at last, so at least that exists as a workaround.  Any clue what's going on with the shell instances though?

Comment: According to [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56427/how-to-modify-ulimit-for-open-files-on-suse-linux-enterprise-server-10-4-permane), [this](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/) and [this](http://www.unix.com/suse/60719-setting-max-open-files-value.html]) you should adjust such settings more than in one place. Have you tried to reboot system? What does `ulimit -Hn` currently shows, your old or new limit?

Comment: I modified the extra files and rebooted as per the linked instructions, but ulimit -Hn / -Sn consistently show 256.  Even running sudo bash -c "ulimit -n 50000" doesn't change it.  If I try to append the script to start the Android Studio executable it returns: "Startup Error: Unable to detect graphics environment"

Comment: okay, add your current `/etc/security/limits.conf` to the question plz and tell me, are new settings applied if you check `ulimit -a` *before* reboot? Also add your `uname -a` and `cat /proc/version` results plz, maybe it's really some kind of bug in specific OpenSUSE release (I checked your case on my OS X and Fedora 18 - all seems good :)

Comment: Edited the answer.  ulimit-a does not apply the settings.  I'll take it there's something wrong with limits.conf, then?

Comment: Look, I did the same thing in my `limits.conf` and here is the output *before* reboot: http://pastebin.com/GtAm7iMG And this is *after* reboot: http://pastebin.com/vrwFdTUw
I'm not sure if you doing all this modifications under the root, are you? Maybe it's stupid question but I want to be sure, because there's almost no way changes made under the root user are not applied.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you should set new values under the root, check them as I did and then switch to your user and check them with `ulimit -Hn/Sn`, if it makes to difference, it may be a bug in this release (but brief search didn't give me any info about it, so..)

Comment: Check http://serverfault.com/questions/569288/ulimit-n-not-changing-values-limits-conf-has-no-effect maybe your `/lib/security/pam_limits.so` isn't looking to `limits.conf`, you should see something like this: 
`[root@crmdev ~]# strings /lib/security/pam_limits.so | grep limits.conf
/etc/security/limits.conf`

Comment: And why are you talking about `/etc/environment/limits.conf`? It's all about making changes in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. Do you have it in your system (you should)? Try `#  find / -type f -iname "*limits.conf*"` under the root, what is shows?

Comment: Sorry, I meant /etc/security/limits.conf.  I was very tired when I posted the question.  I did indeed do it all under root, and pam_limits contains the reference to /etc/security/limits.conf.  However, I updated the question with some mysterious shell output that maybe you know the answer to?  In any case, thanks so much for taking the time to work with me on this; at the very least I can work around the issue with this.

Comment: I'll appreciate if you add `whoami` output to your console trace before you're doing `ulimit -Hn/Sn` every time under different user (I mean, do `whoami`, then `ulimit`, then `su` then repeat etc)

Comment: Sorry about that.  I've appended the whoami to the above log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for now that's what is going on:

```
$ whoami        //session 1 (256)
corey
$ ulimit -Hn
256
$ ulimit -Sn
256
$ su            //session 2 (65k)
$ whoami
root
$ ulimit -Hn
65535
$ ulimit -Sn
65535
$ su corey      //session 3 (65k)
$ whoami
corey
$ ulimit -Hn
65535
$ ulimit -Sn
65535
$ exit      //session 2(65k)
$ exit     // getting back to login shell: session 1 (256)
$ whoami
corey
$ ulimit -Hn
256
$ ulimit -Sn
256
```

The `su` command makes it possible to change a login session's owner (i.e., the user who originally created that session by logging on to the system) *without* the owner having to first log out of that session.
So, when you log out 2 times (from root and corey sessions) you return to the initial session in which your old limits seem to work. I have no idea how this could be if you rebooted system properly, so I just advice you to *relogin* (meaning explicitly log out and log in) under `corey`, I bet new values from `limits.conf` should finally apply.

Comment: Explicitly logging out and relogging in doesn't change anything; I still have to su into myself for the limits to apply.  I have no idea if this is a bug in the distribution or if I've screwed something up, but I'm accepting this answer if only because you've given me a usable workaround to the issue.

Comment: Well, after reading http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/62070.html -- look at the bug #2, I start thinking that maybe your problem is somehow in SELinux policy (it's just a guess, but try to disable SELinux and see what's happened)